# Android make every activity get location information?

Tags: android, android-activity, service, connection

In activity A, I got 2 fragments, from both A1 and A2, user can access to Activity B and Activity C. My problem is, both activity B and C require location information(like Lat, lng). How can I achieve this without huge lag in normal UI drawing?

I have 2 unsuccessful plan:

1. Directly use A to get location, pass values to A1 and A2, and finally pass to B and C. If users are indoors, location information, will take a while to receive. What if user access to B and C without location information?
2. Use a service. However, I don't need location identification for long, also, even service can send broadcast to all, can B and C receive broadcast message before their onCreate()? Also, broadcast take a while to receive, which can affect initialization significantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you have lot of options actually

- Create Bound service with GoogleApiClient in it. Bind this service to activities you need and receive data in them.
- Use Event Bus. Create class with GoogleApiClient to get Location and then just catch datas in activities/fragments you need
- Use Dagger2 to inject GoogleApiClient @module to activities/fragments you need.

Hope I helped you ;)

Comment: That's very helpful! Thank you so much! I have one more question, in these three options, which one is fastest? Since I need to draw UI based on it.

Comment: I prefer working with Service. Because events isn't stable I mean any class with receivers can get data so you can not be sure that you received it where you want it to be. Service is pretty simple: no additional libraries, you can run it even when app is hidden and etc. So i recommend you use it. Hope its helped)

Comment: What about combination of service and Event Bus? Seems it will decouple a lot?

Comment: @LunarS yep it's also possible solution if you don't want to deal with Messenger

Comment: @LunarS no problem ;) Comment here if you have any props with it. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Consider this event bus pattern implementation. The only thing you should consider is to pass a UI thread enforcer.

http://square.github.io/otto/

Comment: It's pretty similar to broadcast, is it faster than broadcast receiver? Broadcast receiver may take a lot time to receive message.

Comment: Also,, can activity not initialized receive posted events after onCreate?

Comment: The library uses reflection to invoke your subscribed methods directly, so it will be much faster since broadcasts are handled by the Android OS, that's why they appear to be slow. There is special @Provide annotation which is for notifying the newly subscribed components.